# Number of Documents Per Day bucket and applied some filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have documents in elasticsearch in which each document looks something like as follows:

```
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA12",
  "status": “CREATED”,
  "type": “ABC”,
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
   "createdAt": "2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z"
}
```

For this document structure, I wanted to get all the documents which are having status as CREATED or SCHEDULED and TYPE is ABC. And in these filtered documents, I want to aggregate the number of documents based on currentDate - createdAt in days bucket. Eg.

- Created Date as today’s date -> Count of documents created today
- Created Date as yesterday’s date -> Count of documents created yesterday

And similarly for last 7 days.

Is there an easy way to do this in a single query?

Comment: Have you tried to create the query? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Opster ES Ninja Nishant, thanks for the question. I was little confused in aggregation here. I know I can write the scripting language for it? But was not sure how can I make the map of date to count easily and also how can I return that? I am still naive in ES. Tried some basic filtering queries and term aggregation queries. But I think this is little complex. Similarly for this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749495/number-of-documents-per-day-bucket-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below mapping, sample docs, aggregation query and response:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_date_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_date_index/_doc/1
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA12",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "type": "ABC",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-06T05:00:00.000Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/2
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA13",
  "status": "SCHEDULED",
  "type": "ABC",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-05T13:41:25.862Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/3
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA14",
  "status": "SCHEDULED",
  "type": "ABC",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-04T06:00:00.000Z"
}

POST my_date_index/_doc/4
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA15",
  "status": "SCHEDULED",
  "type": "ABC",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-03T07:00:00.000Z"
}
```

### Query Request:

```
POST my_date_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,               <----- Remove this to return documents too
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "ABC"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "createdAt": {
              "gte": "now-7d",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "SCHEDULED"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "CREATED"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "createdAt",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've first filtered the documents based on date and the conditions which you've provided.

This would return all the documents. Post which I've applied [date histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) query to get the documents for each and every day on that date range.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_date" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1593993600000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-07-05T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1593907200000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1593820800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-07-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1593734400000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!